# How to use live edit with router script in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I setup live edit in PhpStorm and it works great. While implementing routing in my application, I configured PhpStorm to use a routing script using the Built-in Web Server run configuration. At this point, live edit stopped working because it seems to work only with the built-in webserver and not the PHP built-in web server. (Technically, it didn't stop working, rather there were two run configurations: live edit where the links returned a 404 and a routing configuration that doesn't have live edit.)

- Is it possible to use both live edit and a routing script?
- Does anyone have any workarounds to using live edit or similar functionality when working on an app that uses routing? I currently have a keymap (Alt-R) setup for Reload in Browser.

I'm using PhpStorm 10.0.2 (PhpStorm-143.790) on CentOS 7.

Note: I found two issues relating to live edit and routing but neither was helpful.

1. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-15762
2. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20824

Thanks

Comment: Built-in webserver provides partial support for .htaccess (see https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5508999#5508999). At least this used to work a couple of versions ago:) But, IMO, using the server that already supports HTML5mode to serve your files is a better solution

Comment: @lena Awesome! I didn't think about using a plugin to provide .htaccess support. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

A hint in the 2nd URL above provided a suitable workaround. The key lies in the fact the link between the browser and PhpStorm is not tied to the URL; only the tab. To make this work, you need two run configurations:

1. A `JavaScript Debug` configuration for live edit. Make sure live edit is working.
2. A `PHP Built-in Web Server` configuration with the router script enabled.

Run the `JavaScript Debug` configuration and it will open a tab in Chrome linked to PhpStorm. Then start the `PHP Built-in Web Server` configuration and change the "live edit" tab to the URL for the built-in web server. Any changes will automatically refresh the tab using the `PHP Built-in Web Server` configuration which contains the router functionality.

This concept can also be applied to any functionality not supported by the built-in web server, like SSL. You just need a 2nd web server (built-in or external) and change the live edit tab to the 2nd URL.